# Ayuda con consulta de SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Partiendo del siguiente esquema relacional:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito consultar la empresa que ha construido cada aeropuerto

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
USE Trabajo_bbdd;
SELECT Nombre_empresa, Nombre_aeropuerto
FROM Empresas, Aeropuertos
WHERE Está_construido.Código_aeropuerto = Aeropuertos.código_aeropuerto
AND 
Empresas.NIF_empresa = Está_construido.NIF_empresa;
```

El error que sale es:

```
Mens. 4104, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 4
El identificador formado por varias partes " 
Está_construido.Código_aeropuerto" no se pudo enlazar.
Mens. 4104, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 6
El identificador formado por varias partes "Está_construido.NIF_empresa" no se pudo enlazar.
```

Cómo debería plantearlo para que salga correctamente ? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre otras cosas, te faltaba relacionar la tabla "Está_construido" con las otras dos.

```
USE Trabajo_bbdd;
    SELECT Nombre_empresa, Nombre_aeropuerto
    FROM Empresas
    INNER JOIN Está_construido ON Empresas.NIF_empresa = Está_construido.NIF_empresa
    INNER JOIN Aeropuertos ON Está_construido.Código_aeropuerto = Aeropuertos.Código_aeropuerto
```

Yo evitaría el uso de tildes (o caracteres "especiales") en el nombre de tablas, campos, etc. Aún a día de hoy, siguen causando problemas.

Saludos.